# MongoDB: check if nested key value pair exists

Tags: mongodb, dictionary, find, exists

If got the following database structure:

```
{ "_id" : "rv8MgKMB9qvrcoruW", "object" : "M5ZMiaqPQYP6Pv45y", "matches" : { "mbGLv9hiJJeyEcSoK" : "1", "hTcs5PYp5bXruZSTL" : "1" } }
{ "_id" : "2jksvGbg7fkguECRB", "object" : "M5ZMiaqPQYP6Pv45y", "matches" : { "mbGLv9hiJJeyEcSoK" : "2", "hTcs5PYp5bXruZSTL" : "2" } }
{ "_id" : "a5Ea5evtXkYrcjtLa", "object" : "M5ZMiaqPQYP6Pv45y", "matches" : { "JZKoX3B8gqiwotphb" : "3", "hTcs5PYp5bXruZSTL" : "3" } }
{ "_id" : "RsLhwDS5ERYxERAjX", "object" : "M5ZMiaqPQYP6Pv45y", "matches" : { "mbGLv9hiJJeyEcSoK" : "4", "JZKoX3B8gqiwotphb" : "4" } }
```

and i like to get the data set with a specific object and a specific key value pair in matches.

so e.g.: I like to get the dataset for: "object" : "M5ZMiaqPQYP6Pv45y" AND where is existing a DICTIONARY set "JZKoX3B8gqiwotphb" : "3".

So in this case the output should be:

```
{ "_id" : "a5Ea5evtXkYrcjtLa", "object" : "M5ZMiaqPQYP6Pv45y", "matches" : { "JZKoX3B8gqiwotphb" : "3", "hTcs5PYp5bXruZSTL" : "3" } }
```

I've tried hundreds of combinations and I am currently stuck with:

```
db.Matches.find ({ object: 'M5ZMiaqPQYP6Pv45y', matches: { mbGLv9hiJJeyEcSoK: { '$exists': true, $in: '3' } } })
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [dot notation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/document/#document-dot-notation) to access field of subdocument:

```
db.Matches.find({object: 'M5ZMiaqPQYP6Pv45y', 'matches.JZKoX3B8gqiwotphb': '3'})
```